# Maven dependencies and how they actually work in Java projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, dependencies

I looked for these answers on google but couldn't find exact answers to my questions, usually just an overview on Maven and the pom and the lifecycle phases. My exact questions are:

1. Transitive Dependencies. Say I have a main Java project, called "Project-A", and it has another project as its dependency, say like a Database java project that has all the CRUD methods, called "Dependency-X", that has `spring-boot-starter-jpa-1.X.X` version listed in its POM. Now say I also declare `spring-boot-starter-jpa-2.X.X` (notice the version) directly in Java Project-A's POM. If I understand transitive dependencies correctly, the spring-boot-starter-jpa-1.X.X (from Dependency-X db project) will get imported *transitively* (indirectly) through the Dependency-X (db) project. ***So which dependency wins?*** which gets imported? Being that they are two-different versions, that's obviously a problem. Do you have to **explicitly** add an `<exclusion>` tag to all your dependencies in your POM that PULL in other transitive dependencies that conflict with your projects current dependencies???

i.e.
[image]

2. **Multiple Dependencies**. When you declare dependencies in your pom.xml, what happens when you include the **same** dependency two times which different versions; which gets selected/imported into your project and how does Maven decide that? And I'm assuming, if maven can't find this dependency-a in your first repo listed in your `<repositories>` list (assuming you had more than 1 repo listed) your pom, it will go down the list 1-by-1 until it finds it correct?
   i.e.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mydependency</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency-a</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mydependency</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency-a</artifactId>
            <version>8.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```

3. How exactly is the parent-pom working? I know I can include the `<parent></parent>` tags with a dependency inside, and I can click ctrl + B (windows) or command + B (mac) and it will take me to source pom (parent) and I can view all the contents. How is this working - where is it getting this file from?

Are all "parent" poms, like the "spring-boot-starter-jpa" dependencies *literally* just pointing to POM files on the maven central repo, which further point to individual JARS, that maven resolves and imports into your project???

i.e.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: For two artifacts with same groupid and artifactid the highest version wins.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen No, that is not true. You are probably confusing this with Gradle.

Comment: @JFabianMeier Probably.  I looked at the code for deciding if one version was "greater" that another a long time back - the version parsing was quite intricate until it fell back on simpel string comparison.

Answer (score 1):

As far as resolving transitive dependencies are concerned, the shortest path wins.
This is also documented [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

```
Dependency mediation - this determines what version of an artifact will be chosen when multiple versions are encountered as dependencies. Maven picks the "nearest definition". That is, it uses the version of the closest dependency to your project in the tree of dependencies. You can always guarantee a version by declaring it explicitly in your project's POM. Note that if two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency tree, the first declaration wins.
"nearest definition" means that the version used will be the closest one to your project in the tree of dependencies. Consider this tree of dependencies:
  A
  ├── B
  │   └── C
  │       └── D 2.0
  └── E
      └── D 1.0
In text, dependencies for A, B, and C are defined as A -> B -> C -> D 2.0 and A -> E -> D 1.0, then D 1.0 will be used when building A because the path from A to D through E is shorter.
```

> so which dependency wins? which gets imported?

boot starter jpa 2.x wins since that has the shortest path.

For multiple versions of the same dependency, I would recommend running

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

to see which one gets included or if there is an error.

> How exactly is the parent-pom working?

The parent pom is just a reference to a project which the current project "inherits" from. There are certain rules on how the dependencies are resolved from parents. Most important thing in my opinion is that the parent allows you add dependencies for common sibling projects in a place where all of them can inherit their dependencies from. Spring boot follows this pattern to introduce starter pom version resolution. Offcourse, having a parent pom is optional and you can have a project without one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Usually, the "nearest" dependency wins if you have different versions of the same jar in the dependency tree.
2. You can override this behaviour by explicitly setting a version for a transitive dependency in `<dependencyManagement>`. Don't use exclusions to manage versions.
3. Parents are resolved like dependencies, i.e. from the repositories like MavenCentral.
4. The contents of the parent and of your POM are "merged", leading to the "effective POM" which you can view on command line or in an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

> How exactly is the parent-pom working? I

You seem to want to understand how project inheritance works in Maven.  It is a vast subject. That addresses [the major way to structure a pom (which project inheritance) and the consequences associated to](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) .

About your two first questions :

> So which dependency wins? which gets imported?
>
> what happens when you include the same dependency two times which
> different versions; which gets selected/imported into your project and
> how does Maven decide that?

While your question make sense, Maven doesn't provide any specific guarantee about that over the time. The outcome in case of conflicted version is just an implementation detail.
I prefer tell you that in order to guarantee a consistent packaging according to your requirements in terms of dependency versions, you have to perform a explicit check for that.
You can implement it or just use maven plugins such as [the maven-enforcer-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) with [existing rules](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/index.html) such as :

- dependencyConvergence - ensure all dependencies converge to the same version.
- banDuplicatePomDependencyVersions - enforces that the project doesn't have duplicate declared dependencies.
- requireUpperBoundDeps - ensures that every (transitive) dependency is resolved to its specified version or higher.

The rule lists is really dense and you can even write your own rule if no one matches your need.

Example on how to declare the plugin execution with the dependencyConvergence rule :

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce</id>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <dependencyConvergence/>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```